# reducing the steps in the git workflow

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I have the following setup

```
[dev laptop] -- git push --> [gitlab]
                                 |
                              git pull
                                 |
                                 V
                          [prod server]
```

The above result in the following workflow

1. `dev-laptop$ git push gitlab`
2. `dev-laptop$ ssh prod-server`
3. `prod-server$ cd app`
4. `prod-server$ git pull gitlab`
5. `prod-server$ pm2 restart app`
6. `prod-server$ exit`
7. `dev-laptop$ rsync` images and other binary files between dev and prod

How can I reduce the number of the above steps? Here is what I've thought:

1. get rid of **gitlab** in between so that I `git push` directly from my **dev-laptop** to the **prod-server**. But I don't know how to do this or if it can even be done.
2. set up some `git hooks` on **gitlab** so when I `git push` to it, on `post-receive`, **gitlab** `git push(es)` the changes to the **prod-server**. And, add a `post-receive` git hook on the **prod-server** that restarts `pm2`. Of course, I don't quite know how to do this as well.

<strike>**Update:** Ideally, since I am the only developer in this project, I would like to have a workflow like so</strike>

```
[dev laptop] -- git push --> [prod server]
```

The above, in conjunction with a few `git hooks` as described above, would simplify my life considerably. Of course, the danger is that I don't have a central repo anymore, so in case my **dev laptop** or **prod server** go belly up, I don't have a backup. But that is a danger I can choose to live with.

**Update2:** the safety of having a central repo is very attractive.

Comment: Hi, is there a reason you don't use a standardized CI/CD Process and tool like e.g. VSTS?

Comment: yeah, for one, I have no idea what is VSTS. Two, I want to keep the process as simple as possible. Perhaps if I learned about CI/CD and VSTS, I might be convinced to use them, but it seems unlikely. I have thought of getting rid of `git` completely and just using `rsync` (only for projects where I am the sole developer) but haven't dared down that path yet.

Answer (score 0):

Things to do:

1) first make your prod deploy a single step.  I've seen lots of production sites using `git pull` to do updates, but I think it's a mistake - it's asking for their to somehow be conflicts in the production repo, causing issues.  Instead write a script that does something like

```
mkdir deploydir-next
git archive master https://gitlab.com/me/myproject.git | tar -x -C /deploydir-next
pm2 stop app
mv deploydir deploydir-prev ; mv deploydir-next deploydir
pm2 start app
(cd deploydir-prev ; tar czv ../rollback_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.tar.gz . )
rm -rf deploydir-prev
```

This shuts it down long enough to make a very fast switch to the new code, which is derived from a snapshot of the current head of master.

2) Now that you have a single `deploy` script on your production server, you have options:

1. run it manually when you're ready to deploy
2. run it periodically at a planned upgrade-time (5am Monday is good because it gives you all week to fix any outages without cutting into your weekend)
3. run it automatically via a (secure!) [gitlab webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html)